# How do I convert a .bin file into a .iso file for usb use

Tags: linux, boot, usb, iso-image

I have a .bin file that I would like to convert to an iso to burn to a usb. The .bin file is clearly bootable; The output of

```
file os-image.bin
```

is

```
../os-image.bin: DOS/MBR boot sector
```

and I can boot it in qemu.

but when I convert it to iso:

```
genisoimage -o drip.iso os-image.bin
```

or bchunck or PowerISO or bin2iso

the output of the file command is:

```
drip.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'CDROM'
```

and rufus won't write it to usb, and qemu won't boot.

Also, when I write the bin to the usb with rufus, it won't boot on a regular computer.

Comment: Rufus developer here. If your `.bin` is bootable, then you don't need to convert it to an ISO. Rufus will happily open it and write it to USB. Make sure you use Rufus 3.3 though, as there was a regression in Rufus 3.2 with regards to opening uncompressed bootable disk images (that has since been fixed in 3.3).

Comment: ehh, @Akeo - I think that can'should be an answer, especially since OP has explicitly mentioned your application. Normal disclosure rules apply of course but this feels like a case where you can probably talk about the process, and the fact that it'll only work on a newer version...

Comment: I also said in my answer at the end that it didnt work so any extra tips would be nice @JourneymanGeek

Comment: Well, at this stage, there are still too many unknowns to figure out. Did OP try the `.bin` with Rufus or did they only try the `.iso` they got from the `.bin` with Rufus and not the `.bin` itself on the belief that Rufus can only open `.iso` (which has been my understanding). Also, I'm not sure at this stage if OP is trying to convert a bootable DD image to an ISO (pretty much do the reverse of what Rufus does, which I get asked about on regular basis) or if the `.bin` they are working with is some alternate form of ISO image, that isn't your run of the mill ISO-9660 or UDF 1:1 image.

Comment: i tried with .bn and .iso didnt work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I have figured out the issue.

My image that I was using for writing wasn't for UEFI so it didn't want to boot on newer PCs.